# How to design a database for relational dynamic forms?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, dynamicform

My requirements are:

- Need to be able to dynamically add forms with different fields/field
  types
- A form can include a dropdown that gets filled with the
  values of another

submitted form
Eg : 
Staff form :

1. First name(text box)
2. Last name(text box)
3. Department(dropdown) -> should be bind to department form

Department Form :

1. Department name(dropdown)

Other information:

- My database is SQL server
- I’m looking for performance
- Each table can have more than a million records
- We have more than 1000 users in our system
- We need to get different reports on submitted record by user
- Reports need to have filtering functionality on all columns

Options:

1. Create one table per form
2. add 2 tables for form-structure and field-structure
   then 2 more tables for submitted-form-value and submitted-field-value

Any other option or idea?

Comment: How are you planing on binding the dropdowns to other forms? I didn't understand that part. Other then that, I suggest keep your structure as generic as possible.

Comment: I think if I follow the option 2, my table structure will be:

Comment: I think if I follow the option 2, my table structure will be:  Template_Form_table(form_id,Form_Name) and Template_Field_Table(field_id,field_Name,field_order,form_id,field_datasource) so field_datasource is referenced to the same table (self reference relationship)

Answer (score 6):

Well, I would probably create a database structure like this:

```
-- This table will hold the forms
CREATE TABLE tblForm
(
      Form_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , Form_Name varchar(100)
    -- Any other form related data such as create date, owner etc`
)

-- This table will hold the input types (i.e text box, combo box, radio buttons etc`)
CREATE TABLE tblInputType
(
      InputType_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , InputType_Name varchar(100)
)

-- This table will hold the inputs used in the form
CREATE TABLE tblFormInput
(
      FormInput_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FormInput_Form int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblForm(Form_Id)
    , FormInput_InputType int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblInputType(InputType_Id)
    , FormInput_Name varchar(100)
    , FormInput_DisplayOrder numeric(18,18)
    , FormInput_DefaultText varchar(100)
)

-- This table will hold the texts and values used for combo boxes, radio buttons, check boxes etc`
CREATE TABLE tblFormInputExtraData
(
      FormInputExtraData_FormInput int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblFormInput(FormInput_Id)
    , FormInputExtraData_Text varchar(100)
    , FormInputExtraData_Value varchar(100)
)
```

Points of interest:

1. I've used varchar(100) for all textual data just as an arbitrary
   number for this example. You should choose the appropriate content
   length for your application.
2. I've used varchar also to store the value of inputs such as combo
   boxes and radio buttons, since it's easy. If you intend to use
   non-textual values (such as .Net objects, or images, you should
   change this data type to whatever fits your needs - xml and
   varbinary comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, this is the first point. The second and most interesting point by me is the SQL structure, how to store that data and how to make them available to the SQL view (to be able to use data in datagrid with sorting and filtering), where columns must be also generated dynamically by the form items.